# Fixed menu gets hidden by relative positioned images?

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS:

```
#header-fixed {
  background: url(images/header-fixed-bg.png) repeat-x 0 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #111;
  position: fixed;
  top: -70px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 0 0 4px;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 0 0 4px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 0 0 4px;
}

.large-bg-1 {
  background: url(images/large-bg-1.jpg) repeat 0 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: 50% 0;
  position: relative;
  height: 294px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

I'm using the Parallax background technique (when the background seem to scroll slower than the rest of the page). But no matter how much `z-index` I add to the fixed menu it still gets hidden by them.

How can I solve this?

Here's the live site: http://www.hfwebdesign.com/?ModPagespeed=off

Answer (score 1):

Set the other element's `z-index` to `-1`

Comment: Gah! Why didn't I think of that? Thanks!